# How to use libraries in the browser in javascript?

Tags: html, node.js, browser, nlp, require

'I am trying to use an NLP library in html/css/node.js, but I am having trouble because I can't "require" it on the browser side. Here is my HTML form element which takes the browser input in an index.js file.

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  fetch('/submit', { method: 'POST'}).then((res) =>{ 
    if(res.test) return res.test;
  })
  
  let inputValue = document.querySelector("#submit_box").value;
  score = document.getElementById("score");
  score.textContent = getScore(inputValue, realPhrase, counter);
  counter++;
  console.log()

});
```

I hope to send the results from that form (inputValue) and another variable (realPhrase) to the back end to run this code, with inputValue and realPhrase being variable 1 and 2.

```
const NLPCloudClient = require('nlpcloud');

const client = new NLPCloudClient('paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2','my api key lol')
client.semanticSimilarity([variable1, variable2]).then(function (response) {
       value = response.data})
```

Then, I hope to send the score value back to the front end to be displayed. How should this be done?

I was thinking that I could use HTML get and post requests, but I'm having trouble with that. Then, I tried using middleware, but it seems much too complicated. If any of those are the recommended solutions, I can just go back to it.

Answer (score 0):

[NLP Cloud's docs](https://github.com/nlpcloud/nlpcloud-js) suggest you use the `npm` package manager.

MDN web docs provide a good introduction to [package management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Understanding_client-side_tools/Package_management). Package management is a complicated but necessary part of modern web development. A package manager like `npm` can pull in your dependencies, but you'll need to  provide a means of bundling them into production code, like vite or webpack.

Some libraries provide a pre-bundled `.js` file to use directly as the `src` for a script tag in your HTML document, but I can't find an example of NLP Cloud doing this (it's a less common practice than it used to be).